# Multi step forecasts with Machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset of weekly sale on which I applied ANN, KNN, CART and SVR to generate multi-step ahead forecasts. I directly used the corresponding packages in R. Is this methodology correct?
I came across a [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889) by Prof. Markidakis in which they have used different approaches to generate multi-step ahead forecasts for Machine Learning models. Do I have to use one of the approaches(Direct forecasting, recursive forecasting, Multi neural network forecasting) approaches?

Comment: You get to choose which method you want to use.